# Is this a standard android component?

Tags: android, android-widget

The "Top paid", "Top Free", "Just In" buttons (with green selection indicators) in the picture below...Are these standard components that I can use in my Android application?

I can't seem to find them within the SDK and yet I've seen them here (in the market) and within the Seesmic Twitter Android app.

I would like to use such and effect to allow sorting on one of my listviews. If these are not available then what is the best way to achieve this effect?

[image](http://twitpic.com/10phej)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are just [radio buttons](http://dev.android.com/reference/android/widget/RadioButton.html). Put them in a RadioGroup with a horizontal orientation.

Comment: Is it a custom tab widget, maybe?

Comment: Thanks - how would I theme this to look like the example picture?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know how to exactly get this layout. You will have to experiment in the layout xml code with the parameters for both the RadioGroup and the RadioButton's to see what happens. The Android developers site lists all the available parameters.